# Translation based block cipher

Tags: encryption, block-cipher

The paper ["On the group generated by the round functions of translation based ciphers over arbitrary finite fields"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1821) states:

> **Definition 3.3.** A block cipher $C =  \{ \tau_k | k ∈ K \}$ over $F_q$ is called **translation based** (tb) if:
>
> 1. each $\tau_k$ is the composition of $l$ round functions $\tau_{k,h}$ , for $k ∈ K$, and $h = 1, . . . , l$,
>      where in turn each round function  $\tau_{k,h}$ can be written as a composition $\gamma_h\lambda_h\sigma_{φ(k,h)}$ of three permutations of $V$ , where:
>
>    - $\gamma_h$ is a bricklayer transformation not depending on $k$ and $0\gamma_h = 0$
>    - $\lambda_h$ is a linear permutation not depending on $k$,
>    - $φ : K × \{1, . . ., l\}→ V$ is the key scheduling function, so that $φ (k, h)$ is the $h$-th round key,  given the master key $k$;
> 2. for at least one round index $h_0$ we have that
>
>    - $\lambda_{h_0}$ is a proper mixing layer, and
>    - the map $K → V$ given by $k → φ (k, h_0)$ is surjective, that is, every element of $V$ occurs as an $h_0$-th round key

How do I check if this map is surjective? Is AES a translation based block cipher?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably cannot check this without a somewhat explicit specification of $\varphi.$ In general, if the key scheduling function has a simple structure, and if $|V|=|K|$ this becomes easier; In that case, if  $\varphi(h_0,\cdot)$ is a permutation you are done.